# Ruby - Convert Integer to String

Tags: ruby, arrays

In Ruby, trying to print out the individual elements of a String is giving me trouble. Instead of seeing each character, I'm seeing their ASCII values instead:

```
>> a = "0123"
=> "0123"
>> a[0]
=> 48
```

I've looked online but can't find any way to get the original "0" back out of it. I'm a little new to Ruby to I know it has to be something simple but I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Or you can convert the integer to its character value:

```
a[0].chr
```

Answer (score 7):

You want `a[0,1]` instead of `a[0]`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is changing in Ruby 1.9 such that "asdf"[2] yields "d" rather than the character code

Answer (score 5):

To summarize:

This behavior will be going away in version 1.9, in which the character itself is returned, but in previous versions, trying to reference a single character of a string by its character position will return its character value (so "ABC"[2] returns 67)

There are a number of methods that return a range of characters from a string (see the Ruby docs on the String [slice method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000786)) All of the following return "C":

```
"ABC"[2,1] 
"ABC"[2..2]
"ABC".slice(2,1)
```

I find the range selector to be the easiest to read. Can anyone speak to whether it is less efficient?

Answer (score 2):

The [,] operator returns a string back to you, it is a substring operator, where as the [] operator returns the character which ruby treats as a number when printing it out.

Answer (score 1):

[@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511/ruby-convert-integer-to-string#29513),

That's just how [] and [,] are defined for the String class.

Check out the [String API](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000786).

Answer (score 0):

I think `each_char` or `chars` describes better what you want.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "0123"
=> "0123"
irb(main):002:0> Array(a.each_char)
=> ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
irb(main):003:0> puts Array(a.each_char)
0
1
2
3
=> nil
```