# How can I get Ruby to treat the index of a string as a character (rather than the ASCII code)?

Tags: ruby, string, compare

I am checking to see if the last character in a directory path is a '/'.  How do you get ruby to treat the specific index of a string as a character rather than the associated ASCII code?

For example the following always returns `false`:

```
dir[dir.length - 1] == '/'
```

This is because `dir[dir.length - 1]` returns the ASCII code 47 (rather than '/').

Any thoughts on how to interpret 47 as '/'?  Or is there a completely different way to handle this in the first place?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371333/how-to-extract-a-single-character-as-a-string-from-a-larger-string-in-ruby and possibly other questions

Answer (score 5):

You have to be a bit careful, because the behavior has changed from Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9.

```
# In Ruby 1.8:
"hello"[0] == 104

# In Ruby 1.9:
"hello"[0] == "h"

# In both versions:
"hello"[0] == ?h
"hello"[0, 1] == "h"
```

In general, if you just want to test for equality with a character, you can use the `?x` to signify the character `x` (which will be the ascii code in 1.8 and the string in 1.9), or else use the range form by giving an explicit length. This is assuming you're dealing with ascii only. For unicode, you should probably be using Ruby 1.9.

From your example, the nicest form is probably `dir[-1] == ?/`, or if using Rails (or activesupport), you might prefer `dir.ends_with? '/'`

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret 47 as '/' with `47.chr` which returns `=> "/"`
As a side note, you can use `dir[-1]` to return the last character, rather than `dir[dir.length-1]`

So, this will work in either ruby 1.8 or 1.9:

`dir[-1].chr == '/'`